# Can someone explain to me the algorithm for Restricted Weak Composition by Daniel Page in plain english?

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

I have been trying to understand Daniel Page's algorithm for 
[generating restricted weak composition](http://drpage.pagewizardgames.com/handout_gmrwce_danielpage_mar6.pdf). However, I could not understand it totally. Can someone explain it in more simpler terms?  I do not have a theoretical mathematics background.

Comment: Have you considered asking on http://math.stackexchange.com/ or http://mathoverflow.net/ ?

Comment: OK, there's an abstract and 45 slides. At which point do you encounter something you don't understand? When you say "I do not have a theoretical mathematics background", I wonder how meaninful the *first sentence* of the abstract (namely "Over the past decade, researchers have been trying to seek more generalized algorithms for generating mathematical objects such as finite formal languages, and combinatorial objects.") can be to you?

Answer (score 4):

You can find my paper at http://www.springerlink.com/content/w31081rw26p610t1/?MUD=MP , or my accepted version at http://drpage.pagewizardgames.com/daniel_r_page_GAfRWCG.pdf (please cite the final version, not the accepted version) if you have any questions about the algorithm.  This is the paper on that algorithm.

Comment: Is there any known source code implementation of the Restricted Weak Composition Generation algorithm available anywhere (preferable Java/C/C# but any will do)?